# How to find neighbour elements?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I don't know what is name of this kind of algorithm so I am looking for it: group elements from array (which is contains objects which has x and y coordinates), so depends on this coordinates I want to create arrays which containes neighbour elements (and neighbour elements in this case means: elements which is horizontally or vertically next to each other). I am trying to find the most efficiant.(using language: javascript).
[image: I added excel sheet image for more clarification]

Comment: Any chance you could provide the dataset which you would like to search? What have you tried till now? It seems you just need to iterate the rows / cols based on your x/y coordinates.

Comment: my question was bad :? :/

Comment: I think sorting your coordinates by both x and y axis would be a start. For any given coordinate, you would know as many neighbors as you wish.

Comment: firstly I don't understan why wrote -1, what was wrong on this question, tell me and I will correct :/. and yes iterate array and match each other every time it is my idea too but I think this is worst one

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted your question :) I was just trying to help.

Comment: How to avoid downvotes: provide the JavaScript code you have been trying with. If you did not try anything at all, then please first start with that. There is not a lot of appreciation for questions that show no research effort.

Comment: sorry then ^_^ and thank you for helping ^_^

Comment: Neither was I, but from SO perspective, it isn't a very good question, as you are looking for an algorithm, maybe a sub site would have been better to ask the question, as there isn't a real programmers problem here

Comment: btw, the image does not explain something. neither the data structure nor the problem with it.

Comment: I didn't know that :/ ok I will ask somewhere else.

Comment: @trincot: reinventing the wheel is not always the best approach. The OP might have suspected that this problem is known and has efficient solutions. He is right to ask, not knowing a proper name.

Comment: I am not fluent English speaker but I am trying as hard as possible to write good questins,  thanks anyway, I am not asking any questions without providing any code.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the OP did not show research effort. I am not suggesting re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @trincot: you are requesting some source code, which means that you expect the OP to start programming even before he knows about the wheel.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I ask for source code, because without code nothing will happen. I did not say that code could not rely on some library. Someone who takes the effort to research will find documented algorithms, possibly libraries or examples to draw from.

Comment: @trincot: how would you formulate a query to find the relevant solutions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I would not. I would first search for algorithms with a simple search like "group points that are nearby algorithm", which may not give the desired algorithm immediately, but spending 5 minutes of research will be very enlightening. It is not up to the StackOverflow community to do this on behalf of the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I got it, I spent 5minute and more too but when I couldn't find it I asked if someone knew this knid of algorithm. I don't ask anyone to spent their time to reserch it. It took couple of second to write algorithm name if you know, and if not just ignore question. But still I understand your point and I will keep it mind for next time : )

Answer (score 1):

This is called *connected components labeling*.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#Algorithms

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @BackSlash: I don't think so. The OP is essentially asking the name of the problem.

Comment: Sure its not *connected neibor labeling*

Comment: thank you, I am gonna look at it. and someone tells me why I got -1 I will correct my question : /